# Facebook API: Get comments from facebook posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I am trying to retrieve all comments on a shared LINK.

I have tried FQL on comment table, but that doesn't work since comment table is for comments plugin.

Let me give you an example:
- CNN has shared a link on their page, which has 60 likes and 30 comments. 
- I have tried this FQL query, but it returns nothing since it is not from Comments plugin:
FQL: SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time FROM comment
WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url =
'http://google.com/')

So any solution on this?

Comment: _“CNN has shared a link on their page, which has 60 likes and 30 comments.”_ – does the link itself have the likes and shares – or the _post_ …?